# Show li elements in div while height is less than another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two divs with `id=left` and `id=right`. The div with `id=left` contains some `li` elements (a list with bullets) and it is floated left. The div with `id=right` contains some text and html (any type of content). The problem is sometimes the left sided div (`id=left`) is bigger than `id=right` or vice versa. I want only to show, for example 10 `li`s on the page and then when user scroll to show another `li`s on the page while the height of `left` is less than or equal to the height of `right`.

A descriptive image of the problem:

[image: Want to show only some li elements from left box to have the same size with right box.]

**EDIT:**
I can retreive from server a list of 1000 lis and use display: none and on scroll `display: block`. **I don't want to load dinamically from the server the `li`s.**

Width: #left is `250px` #right is `750px`.

Comment: where is your code?\

Comment: @TributetoAPJKalamSir +1 to your comment for the username you have!! :)

Comment: I haven't a code because I asked how to do this. I searched on google SO for similar things but with no success.

Comment: So, what do you want that happened to the links on the left when they are too many?

Comment: @MMPP it is unclear for me. what exactly do you want?

Comment: I want only to show, for example 10 li on the left div and then when user scroll, to show another li in the left div while the height of left is less than or equal to the height of right.

Comment: Okay, this is worded so that it is VERY confusing.  Are you saying that in the case of #right being taller than #left, you want to dynamically, and lazily load additional `<li>`s from your server, until they get to the bottom of #right?

Comment: I can retreive from server a list of 100 `li`s and use `display: none` and on scroll `display: block`. I don't want to load dinamically from the server.

Comment: Is the width of the `#left` or `#right` changes dynamically? if not, then would that be atleast with percentage or fixed known width?

Comment: @Mr_Green #left is `250px` #right is `750px`.

Comment: I am so sorry for the confusion I made!

Comment: @MMPP you can have max-width if something is stretching too much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#left").height( $("#right").height() );  

    $(window).scroll( function(){
        if($(window).scrollTop() >= $('#right').offset().top + $('#right').outerHeight() - window.innerHeight) {

        } else {
            $('.hideme').each( function(i){

                var bottom_of_object = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();
                var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

                if( bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object ){

                    $(this).animate({'opacity':1},500);

                }

            });
        }

    });

});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="left">
    <li>Hello</li>
    <li>Hello</li>
    <li>Hello</li>
    <li>Hello</li>
    <li>Hello</li>
    <li>Hello</li>
    <li class="hideme">Fade In</li>
    <li class="hideme">Fade In</li>
    <li class="hideme">Fade In</li>
    <li class="hideme">Fade In</li>
    <li class="hideme">Fade In</li>
    <li class="hideme">Fade In</li>
</div>
<div id="right">
Your text here
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#left
{
    height:auto; 
    width: 250px;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
}
#right {
    float: right;
    width: 200px;
}
#left li
{ 
    margin:10px; 
    padding:50px; 
    background-color:lightgreen; 
}
.hideme
{
    opacity:0;
}
```

Check JS Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/e5qaD/4000/

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned in comments that `#left` has `250px` width and `#right` has `750px` width.You can get that behavior when you apply `position: absolute` to the `#left` container.

```
body, html {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.main {
    position: relative;    /* To contain #left */
}
#left {
    background-color: skyblue;
    overflow: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;          /* top and bottom values are to stretch the #left inside the parent container */
    width: 250px;
}
#right {
    background-color: tomato;
    width: 750px;
    margin-left: 250px;       /* equal to #left's width */
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rerLdxeb/)**

NOTE: In the fiddle above, I used `br` tags to break the line. which I used just for fiddle purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alaksandarjesus/pw2qr0fk/5/)

I have used jquery to dynamcially set the height at time of load. If you are changing the content you need to call setmenuheight function after loading the content if you are going for different pages. I am not sure, how you are going to code the content.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    for(var i = 1; i < 100; i++){   
        var menuli = "<li>"+"Menu - " +i+"</li>";
    $("#left ul").append(menuli);
    };

setmenuheight();

});


function setmenuheight(){

      $("#left").height($(".content").height()+"px");

}
```

Comment: Add and delete lorem ipsum text to see the list change. You need to click run after adding or deletion

Comment: Thank you for helping me! +1

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this with a little bit of jQuery:

#### HTML

```
<div id="left">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
    ...
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="right">
   lorem ipsum ...
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
#left{
    width: 250px;
    float:left;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
#right{
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 750px;
    float: right;
}
```

#### jQuery

```
var $right = $('#right'), var $left = $('#left');

if($right.height()<$left.height()){
    $left.height($right.height());
}

$(window).on('scroll', function () {
    $('#left').scrollTop($(this).scrollTop());
});
```

#### Fiddles

css only: http://jsfiddle.net/tomsarduy/88eag6e7/2/
jquery: http://jsfiddle.net/tomsarduy/88eag6e7/1/